# When does a REST API stops being one in terms of state management?

Tags: rest, state, redis, spring-boot

As far as I understand, there is no certain boundaries for the RESTness of an API. However, I would like your help to understand how large and long (in terms of running time) a caching or state mechanism would be fine to use with a REST API goal in mind.

I read about stateless being no short lived state. The database persisted state is fine etc.

For example, is generally accepted idea around holding a JWT token somewhere around let's say a spring security context or using redis for caching leans towards they damage RESTness or they're fine as long as they have short lived time?

I would appreciate any suggested readings also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statelessness in REST means that *transaction* state is not maintained between requests.

for example say i have an eCommerce api where i can purchase a "basket" of items

A Stateful API might expose

- ListItemsForSale()
- NewBasket(customer)
- AddItem(item)
- PurchaseBasket(paymentDetails)

the client would call each in turn and the API would keep track of the basket contents and the customer over the life of the entire transaction.

A Stateless API on the other hand would expose

- ListItemsForSale()
- BuyBasket(items, customer, paymentDetails)

Because it doesn't maintain the state of each clients order, you have to send the all the information required for a transaction in a single request and maintain the state on the client side.

Things like database connection and downstream api keys are server state. They are unrelated to individual client transactions and you don't need to consider them for the S in REST.

When the API is persisting client info to a database, say after you purchase the basket here is saves your order for processing, can be a grey area. But in general it doesn't count if its an end state of a transaction.

So if you implemented my stateful example here with a database to avoid in memory state on the api, you would end up with loads of un purchased abandoned baskets over time. REST is saying that holding that state in the API is a bad thing, that you can scale better and have a better API if you don't do it.

Comment: Can we say sending the same JWT token in every request and checking if it is valid in server side does not affect RESTness due to authorization being stored in server state? Meaning sending certain values along with the request is acceptable if it's used along the server state or it being not transaction specific.

Comment: a jwt contains the auth state, so its stateless either way

Comment: @yokus: The JWT is not part of the application's "state."  In a sense, it lives *outside* of the application.  Its sole purpose is security validation; it has no effect whatsoever on the application's business logic.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RobertHarvey and Ewan.